# Fontscopy amsfonts?

Tags: math-fonts

I would like to ask if a package {amsmath, amsthm, amsfonts, amssymb, amscd} for use on Windows For example on Microsoft Word or Notepad.
I mean that I can only copy the Fonte in the font folder and just use it.

Comment: I don't think there is anything stopping you. These fonts are freely usable. Note sure whst you'd use them for in word, but thst is another matter.

Comment: have you maybay a Link for Download?

Comment: Nope, you'll have to run through ctan yourself (hence my wonder why you'd even do this)

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: the fonts are in a very specific encoding so practically unusable by anything except TeX. there are no licence issues but if you want a tex-like math font for Word don't use the classic ams fonts use an opentype fonts as used with unicode-math and xetex, so latin modern math ffor example.

Comment: ok ,Thank You , now i understand the Problem .

Answer (score 3):

The original fonts are in a very specific encoding so practically unusable by anything except TeX. There are no licence issues but if you want a tex-like math font for Word don't use the classic ams fonts use an opentype fonts as used with unicode-math and xetex, so latin modern math for example.

http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/lm-math/download/index_html

(which includes a test docx file for use with Word)